# Send remote notification to apple watch over wifi

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, watchkit

I'm developing an app with a watchkit integration and am trying to get the watch to receive a push notification over wifi even if the phone is paired with is disconnected (in this case in airplane mode).
But notifications are not going through to the watch when I try to send them to the paired device token. Which I suppose is to be expected. But is there a way to send a notification directly to the watch? Without having to rely on the watch being connected to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with their doc it seems impossible for the watch to receive remote notifications if the phone is disconnected.

> 1. To receive SMS from third-party apps, MMS from third-party apps, or **push notifications from third-party apps** on your cellular model of Apple Watch, your paired **iPhone must be powered on and connected** to Wi-Fi or cellular, but it doesn't need to be nearby. You also need to be signed in to iMessage on your iPhone.

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205547